# Where can I find apache error_log on CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2

I'd like to know where can I find apache's error log.
According to a website that I read, it should be at /var/log/httpd/error_log
But I don't have the httpd directory on /var/log

Comment: It is where you described it. Probably you never started apache and therefore this directory did not get created. Or you have you custom build configuration. Did you maybe install some hosting control panel software?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check your httpd.conf

The LogFile variable tells you where apache is writing logs.  This value is often (always?) relative to the ServerRoot variable.

Answer (score 11):

Chances are it's in /var/log/httpd.

Do you have `locate` installed?  Have you run `updatedb` recently, or have it `cron`ified?  If so, you can do `locate error_log`.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at your /etc/httpd.conf file and check where you are writing your logs valter. as Raffael says it maybe that you've got them being written to odd locations. check that your httpd server actually started too! :-)

Comment: I found the following line on httpd.conf, in other server:
ErrorLog logs/error_log

Comment: check in /etc/logs or /var/logs or set a full path there '/var/logs/httpd/error_log'

Comment: @Khushil could you explain to us why the config file says `logs/error_log` but the actual log files goes to `/var/logs/...`?

Comment: @LucasPottersky There should be a comment in httpd.conf stating that ServerRoot is prepended to paths like `logs/error_log`. That likely points to `/etc/httpd`, which should contain symlinks to `/var/logs/...`.